# How to re-add added files (update staged files only) in git?

Tags: git, git-add

We have modified files in `path/to/another/` and `path/to/main/`.
Files in `path/to/main/` already added into git cache but we have updated `path/to/main/Bar.php` file **AGAIN**. We now have the following situation:

```
$ git status
[...]
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   path/to/main/Foo.php
        modified:   path/to/main/Bar.php

Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   path/to/main/Bar.php
        modified:   path/to/another/Aaa.php
        modified:   path/to/another/Bbb.php
```

(note that path/to/main/Bar.php shows up twice)

I need a command which could readd files which were added before without using particular paths.

P.S. `git add --update` will add all these files. It doesn't work.

P.P.S. This command should be able to readd `modified:` and `new file:` types.

**UPD1**

Thanks to @AyonNahiyan, yeah, it can work in bash. But maybe there is a command without using bash tricks (subcommands).

Comment: you can perform `git reset` then `git add`s again

Comment: When you did `git reset` your will lost files list. It doesn't work.

Comment: Which files are lost? I don't get what you mean

Comment: Did you mean "readd". Perhaps, yes, "stage". If we're talking about result of `git add`.

Comment: @potame, `git reset` will drop files from "stage". Let's imagine we have 20 files in different directories. It's a disaster. :)

Comment: Then use `git reset -- path/to/main/Bar.php` if you only want to remove a single file. Then `git add path/to/main/Bar.php` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123282/discussion-between-kirby-and-potame).

Comment: possible dupe of [Refresh staged files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006462/refresh-staged-files)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This shows list of files that are only staged:

```
git diff --name-only --cached
```

Now stage these files with their new changes(It will work in bash)

```
git add $(git diff --name-only --cached)
```

PS: (precondition) You need to be at the root of your git repo while running these commands. Running in any subfolder won't work

Comment: I suppose you mean `git add $(git diff --name-only --cached)`. Yeah, it works.

Comment: FYI: breaks for `deleted` files. But super useful

Comment: Very useful command, thanks. Only problem is, it gives out full file paths, so if you are not in the root of your git repo, this wont work

Answer (score 13):

`git update-index` can be used for this purpose.

In particular,

```
git update-index --again
```

should work.

The `--again` option selects the files already in index that are different from `HEAD`.

And the actual action of `update-index` is to pull into index the new contents of those files.

Comment: Yeah, it is. But there is a performance issue. I have 24k+ files in git and I was trying to readd the only file and it's too slow. :( Perhaps it tries to add all files from cache.

Answer (score 7):

```
git update-index --again
```

will do what you want. Note that this command operates on the current working directory (and subdirectories, recursively) by default. If you want to apply the command to the whole repo, add a [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec):

```
git update-index --again :/:
```

`:/:` here means "the root of the working tree".

P.S. you can add an alias for this command to your `.gitconfig` file, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    readd = update-index --again :/:
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ayon works.
A possible fix for deleted files is to add another parameter.

```
--diff-filter=d
```

This excludes all deleted files from "git add".
Further information on how to use this parameter can be found on this thread:
[Filter git diff by type of change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879501/filter-git-diff-by-type-of-change)